# Questions of [pytorch] are going to the [torch] tag

Tags: discussion, support, tags, retag-request

There are two tags:

- [pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch): [PyTorch](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch), the widely used Python [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) (ML) / [deep learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning) (DL) framework.
- [torch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/torch): [Torch7](https://github.com/torch/torch7), the LuaJIT ML/DL framework, which can be considered dead at present. (It hasn't had any development since 2019, and has no active community.)

The ambiguity comes from the fact that PyTorch is imported in Python as `import torch`, and because [torch7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/torch7) is tagged as [torch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/torch) instead of [torch7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/torch7).

As of now, almost all of the questions in [torch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/torch) are actually [pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch) questions. So PyTorch questions are actually being divided into two streams instead of going to a unified pool.

Off the top of my head, I believe something could be done like [pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch) taking the [torch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/torch) tag over as a synonym, and older questions on Lua & Torch7 be specifically tagged under a more specific tag, [torch7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/torch7).

---

Statistics:

- 19,622 questions tagged [pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch)
- 2,021 questions tagged [torch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/torch)

  - Of which, 499 are also tagged [lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua)
  - And 747 are also tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)
  - And 787 are also tagged [pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch)
  - And 442 are triple tagged with [torch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/torch), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch)

If my mental arithmetic serves me, that leaves quite a lot of questions tagged with [torch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/torch) (~500) without auxilliary tags to identify things further.

Comment: *Even* if [[tag:torch]] was renamed to [[tag:torch7]] I'm not sure that would stop people; users don't (can't) read. Disambiguation is the solution here, but is there a "better" name for Torch7's tag?

Comment: I don't think this is the first meta question about this.

Comment: [torch-lua] might work

Comment: @PeterMortensen I searched for pytorch and torch and glanced through all the questions, decided to open this as I couldn't find anything. [tag:torch-lua] seems specific and verbose enough that it might just work.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I'm more of a fan of putting the language first, rather than last, so [tag:lua-torch] and [tag:python-torch]. IMO, having the language first makes it a bit less likely that people just stop reading after the "torch" in "torch-lua".

Comment: @Makyen Yeah, I was considering commenting that as an alternative. Randomly remembered that the general convention is the language first. I don't mind either way though, we'll pick the option most consistent with other tags

Comment: I vote for [tag:lua-torch] (as Ubuntu calls it [`lua-torch-torch7`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/lua-torch-torch7)) and [tag:pytorch] (official, common usage).

Comment: Tag Tags in a Title with `[...]`... => `[pytorch]` + `[torch]`...

Answer (score 16):

This seems like a very reasonable retagging request, but the volume of questions to be processed makes it fiddly to be done by manual processing.  I'm writing this to give people something to vote up or down on.

- The new tag [lua-torch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua-torch) should be created with an appropriate wiki entry.  It should probably note that the project seems to be in suspended animation, at best.
- The questions currently tagged with both [lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua) and [torch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/torch) should be automatically retagged to replace [torch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/torch) with [lua-torch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua-torch).
- The questions currently tagged with [torch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/torch) and either [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) or [pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch) or both should be automatically retagged so that they end up with just two tags: [pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).
- The remaining questions, of which there should be about <s>500</s> 471, will need to be processed manually via a burnination process — individually assessed and either retagged with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch) or retagged with [lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua) and [lua-torch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua-torch) (or perhaps some questions will need a completely different treatment, such as removing any Torch-related tag altogether).
- Finally, as suggested by [Matthieu M](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147192/matthieu-m) in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421789/questions-of-pytorch-are-going-to-the-torch-tag/421810?noredirect=1#comment936980_421810), the [torch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/torch) tag could be blacklisted to ensure it is not revived.  However, the tag itself should vanish automatically once it has been removed from all questions, and it requires some reputation to create a tag, so it isn't clear how crucial this step is.

I'm not sure whether moderators or staff have tools to do an automatic retagging as I've suggested (but if they don't, now would be a good time to write such tools).

Comment: Looks like 471 currently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/torch+-python+-lua+-pytorch

Comment: Thanks, @o11c.  That's in pretty good agreement with my round-figures estimate.

Comment: I would suggest adding one step: [tag:torch] itself should be black-listed, so it isn't spuriously revived.

Comment: I've been thinking about how do these fairly straightforward disambiguations. There might be a way for moderators to perform *most* of the splitting of the tag into different tags. It's not straightforward, in fact it's a bit convoluted, but it's probably something which we can script substantial portions of. In addition, brief testing indicates that it can probably be done, at least mostly/largely, without causing the question to be "active", so not bringing it to the top of each tag's "active" list. I still need to perform more detailed experimentation, and at least some scripting.